# How do I re-execute a jQuery when an operation is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Let me start from scratch. I am developing a website which has two components `text area` : not an input text area, its a `well`, where text will appear whenever a button is clicked. The second component is a `button`, which when clicked a random quote should appear in the `well`. This button when clicked  calls the API which is deployed on an external server, where the `Access-Control` is not set to `public`. This API fetches data from a data base which has many quotes and their Authors. in JSON format. 
Now, to bypass this `Access-Control`, I have used JSON Padding `JSONP. 
But the objective here is that whenever the API is invoked using the jQuery i.e., whenever the button is clicked, the query must fetch a random quote by firing the API. And also, the quote must keep changing to a new quote whenever the button is clicked.

This is my code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").each(function(index){
   $(this).on("click", function() {
   $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(key) {
   $("#quote span").replaceWith(key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</p>");
         });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
<style>
.position-message{
  
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-bottom:20%;
}

.background{
  background-color: rgb(170,180,200);
  border-radius:10%;
}
.button-shape{
   border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    
    margin: auto;
}


#page{
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top:2%;
  margin-bottom:2%;
}
#page-background{
  background-color: maroon;
}
#click{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.quote-shape{
border-radius: 10%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<Title>Click to get quotes</Title>
   <body id="page-background">
      <div class="background" id="page">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="col">
            <div class="row-xs-6">
               <div id="quote" class="well position-message quote-shape"><span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
   
            <div class="row-xs-6">
               <div class="row text-center">
                  <button type="button" id="click" class="button-shape"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is a snapshot of my page:
[image: WebPage snapshot]

The first call was working. But when I try firing the API again by clicking the button, the quote is not changing. This is the problem I am facing. Please let me know how to make the quote change whenever the API is fired.

Comment: Just FYI, this `$("#click").each(function(index){ $(this).on("click", function() {` is unnecessary. `$('#click').on('click', function () {` would work too.

Comment: `$("#click").each` makes no sense. The `#` in `#click` selects by ID, and HTML IDs must be unique, so a loop would only ever loop once, over the single possible element it could locate.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, that too. Even if it was a class and there were more than one element with that class,  the `each` would be superflous.

Comment: Anyway the problem is you're replacing the span with just some text, so next time you run it there's no span into which to insert the content. The answer below should resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `replaceWith()` as it will replace the element you're trying to match preventing future operations (`$('#quote span')` will not match, because the span has been replaced from the first operation). Try simply `.html()` to preserve the span as I've done below (Also, I've applied some simplification from the comment section above):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("//quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(key) {
      $("#quote span").html(key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</p>");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.position-message{
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-bottom:20%;
}

.background{
  background-color: rgb(170,180,200);
  border-radius:10%;
}

.button-shape{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px; 
  margin: auto;
}

.quote-shape{
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#page{
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top:2%;
  margin-bottom:2%;
}
#page-background{
  background-color: maroon;
}
#click{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<Title>Click to get quotes</Title>
</head>
  <body id="page-background">
    <div class="background" id="page">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="col">
            <div class="row-xs-6">
               <div id="quote" class="well position-message quote-shape"><span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
   
            <div class="row-xs-6">
               <div class="row text-center">
                  <button type="button" id="click" class="button-shape"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @FrankerZ thank you for the reply, but why am I getting `The JSONP callback function is invalid.` I have got this many times, but haven't figured out why.

Comment: @GauravThantry The code is working perfectly in the snippet, with the provided URL.

Comment: Thank you @Franker. Maybe the issue is with my browser.

Comment: One last thing. Can you tell me when do we use ajax? Like in what scenarios?

Comment: When you want to make a web request with javascript?

Comment: yeah. Like what type request that would require ajax?